# how to convert Javascript Date to iOS date format

Tags: ios, iphone, json, uitableview

I am new in iOS development. Actually I am trying to show some information which I get from a web service in a table view.
I have successfully retrieved the response as JSON in my code, but in my table view there is a label to show date.
But in my response the date is something like this

```
/Date(1391068800000)/
```

How can I convert this to show in my table view? I think this is Javascript date.
But I'm not sure how to convert it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date in your response is a timestamp. You can create a date object by:
`NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1391068800000];`

After that you can convert this date to a string in an appropriate format by using the `NSDateFormatter` class. For example:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];  
[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];  
NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
```

For more information about formatting dates see: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html

Comment: too me it looks like in ms and not a unix timestamp`

Comment: You're right, it looks like ms. In that case first divide it by 1000. Then you have a timestamp.

Answer (score 3):

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[your timestamp doublevalue]/1000];
```

divide value by 1000 cause of milliseconds (13 digit)